# How can I reference a namespace within an assembly which has whitespace in the name?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, whitespace

When trying to reference any namespace contained within an assembly which has whitespace in the name, I run into this problem:
[image]

**Besides changing the assembly name to something without whitespace**, do I have any options for referencing namespaces within an assembly such as this?

In compliance with the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Requirements:

### To Reproduce:

1. Create new WPF Project. Name it whatever, it doesn't matter.
2. Add to the solution a new Class Library (.Net Framework).

   1. Name the Class Library "Assembly With Space".
3. Build solution.
4. Reference the Class Library project in the WPF project.
5. Replace contents of `App.xaml` within the WPF project with the following ( please take note of the class name, and replace `YourWPFProjectNameHere` with the name of your WPF project ):

   `<Application
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:aws="clr-namespace:AssemblyWithSpace;assembly=Assembly With Space"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       x:Class="YourWPFProjectNameHere.Program" />`
6. Attempt to build solution. You should see the errors presented above.

### EDIT: Duplicate question does not answer how to reference namespace in assembly when you are not the author.

The question asked and this question address the same issue in a similar context. The question asked does not have an answer for how to reference a namespace within an assembly that contains spaces when you do not have control over the code for that assembly. To the best of my knowledge, you cannot add

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://SomeURL.foo", "My.Namespace.Here")]
```

in that instance.

Comment: What is the intend behind having whitespaces in assembly name?

Comment: @RamiShareef Nothing in particular, but in the event it should come up in a situation outside of my control, it would be nice to know how to properly handle it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to reference (in XAML) an assembly with spaces in its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330211/is-there-any-way-to-reference-in-xaml-an-assembly-with-spaces-in-its-name)

Comment: @KlausGütter Definitely, but the question this duplicates does not address how to reference namespaces in assemblies for which dev is not the author.

Comment: Seems like a restriction of "clr-namespace:" that assembly names cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but based on my knowledge on Linux consoles and accessing files that has white spaces my guess will be something on the long the lines of `the\ name\ of\ the\ thing`. To avoid it make sure there aren't any white spaces in the first place.

Worth a try though.

Comment: That\ Didn't\ Work. :-( Thanks anyway though.