# Unknown build error, mapping URI is not valid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, nuget

I have the following defined in my XAML file:

```
xmlns:databaseDesign="clr-namespace:My_Namespace;assembly=My Assembly Name
```

Intellisense picks it up without any issue and I can use autocomplete to grab classes and whatnot from that assembly in my XAML. However, when I go to build, I get the following error:

> Error MC1000: Unknown build error,
>   ''clr-namespace:My_Namespace;assembly=My Assembly Name' mapping URI is
>   not valid. Line 14 Position 14.'  (14, 14)

The only thing I can think of that is different from my previous similar projects is that I am referencing an assembly from a private nuget repo rather than directly from the solution.

Using .NET Core 3.1 for both this project and the referenced library.

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Related? [Is there any way to reference (in XAML) an assembly with spaces in its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5330211/1364007)

Comment: I saw that, both links are dead unfortunately, and after a Google search for the source of one, the recommendation (tag an assembly using XmlnsDefinition) seemingly doesn't work in Core as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, assembly names with spaces aren't handled, with no indicator that this is the issue. Really, Microsoft?

Comment: Welp, apparently so. Probable solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10801073/6693304